# JS image slider with images of any dimensions?

Tags: javascript, slider

All image sliders I've used so far require to provide same sized images. Today I need a slider displaying images of any dimensions. For example, the slider would be 600px * 300px and so would display images that all appear to be 600px * 300px. However one image could be actually 1080 * 500, another 700 * 450, etc.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739908/make-image-fill-div-completely-without-stretching, but I have updated a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/HsE6H/56/

Comment: William: the problem is that in this case, images are only partially visible. For instance, you may end up seeing only the ceiling of a room whereas the picture actually shows the whole room.