# How do i get different sized images into 100x100px divs without aspect ratio getting messed up. (with overflow hidden)

Tags: html, css

Here is a JSFiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/p4toy2qq/.
The Code is here:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="image-of-any-size.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; border: black solid 1px; margin: 10px;}
.container img { width: 100%; }
```

I basically want different sized images to fill out the divs, without the aspect ratio getting messed up. The overflow should be hidden, so the parts outside get 'cropped' off.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you want the images to cover the complete height. and crop the width to keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: may this links helps you out: [Make image fill div completely without stretching][1]

BR!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739908/make-image-fill-div-completely-without-stretching

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9h571x9k/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to set them as background images you can use:

```
.container{
    background: url('something.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Note that some older browsers don't support `background-size`: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 1):

there's a method to do this.

```
.img-container{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
}
```

horizontal img

```
.img-container > img{
position:absolute;
top:0;
height:100%;
}
```

vertical img

```
.img-container > img{
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bh64npgd/1/)

Comment: here with a demo and image centering in the container this does need to add a class according to the orientation of the image. : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ktb3jngs/1/

Comment: BTW your demo is the same as the OP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover the height of the images inside the container, use `background-image: auto 100%` style instead of `img` tag and apply the image to the `.container` element directly.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4toy2qq/3/)**

**Note**: This solution is assuming that all your images have more than `100px` of height as you have shown in the fiddle.

### Update:

If you want to just cover the image completely inside the container then you can use `background-image: cover`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4toy2qq/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

### You could use the new `object-fit` property ([currently webkit only](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

1) Set `object-fit: cover;` on the image to ensure that the aspect ratio is kept,  and

2) Set height: 100px to fill the box if the image is < 100px high.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p4toy2qq/5/)**

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: black solid 1px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://chennaionline.com/images/gallery/2013/June/20110623010938/Singam2_Suriya_Stills_Photos_Images_10.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.moviehdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/happy_diwali__sms_images_.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>
```

You can read more about this new property in this [webplatform article](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/object-fit).

From the above article - regarding the 'cover' value:

> The whole image is scaled down or expanded till  it fills the box
>   completely, the aspect ratio is  maintained. This normally results in
>   only part of the image being visible.

Also, here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n8qxcp4b/1/) from the above article which demonstrates all the values of the `object-fit` property.