# How to fill div with image

Tags: html, css, image

i have this responzive grid and I dont know hot to remove space between top and bottom of div. How to fill with image whole div? You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/jo3jorch/1/

```
<div>
<img src="http://beyondeurope.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Top_10_Universities_in_New_York_City.jpg">
</div>

div {
   width: 50%;
   float: left; 
}
div img {
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

https://jsfiddle.net/b7nxzt8m/1/

this was missing

```
img {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Didn't notice that :)

Comment: You might want to mark the question as answered :-)

Comment: Am I just dumb or is your fiddle really identical to OP's?

Answer (score 1):

If regardless of the page width you're only having issues with the top and bottom of the image leaving space, you need height 100% rather than width:

HTML:

```
<div id="newyork">
    <img src="http://beyondeurope.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Top_10_Universities_in_New_York_City.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#newyork {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: red;
}

#newyork img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jo3jorch/8/

But if the space can sometimes appear top and bottom, there is a good answer to responsive image resizing here: [Make image fill div completely without stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739908/make-image-fill-div-completely-without-stretching)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: RobertStettler's answer is the one to go for.

Just add `font-size: 0` to parent of divs, in your case to `body` and later restore it on children.

```
body { font-size: 0 }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jo3jorch/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to add "display: block" to "div img". Images are actually textual elements, and therefore get the text gutter for the low-hanging bottoms of "g" and "j" and stuff.