# How to ensure the image inside a DIV resizes with browser resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Works fine (the image fills up the DIV and resizes based on browser size):

```
<div class="pageImgHdrMain">
    <div id="pageImgHdrSub">
        <div class="pageImgHolder" style="background: #fcf;">
            <img src="theImages/dummyBanner.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work, the image is stretched out and cuts off as the browser resizes:

```
<div class="pageImgHdrMain">
    <div id="pageImgHdrSub">
        <div class="pageImgHolder" style="background: #fcf;">
            <div id="ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_SpecialtyContentBlockImg">
                <div>
                    <div style="display:none;" align="left"></div>
                    <p><img src="art.jpg" alt="ArtThumbOne" title="ArtThumbOne" class=""><br></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pageImgHdrMain
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.pageImgHdrSub
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
}
.pageImgHolder
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 337px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pageImgHolder div div p img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I think what is messing it up is there are nested DIV inside the main DIV.

How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: In your css can't you just use .pageImgHolder img {width: 100%;} ?

Comment: @FunkDoc I doubt it because there are other nested DIV before I get get to img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are all the inner unnamed divs for?

I think what you need is to set the `#ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_SpecialtyContentBlockImg` to `position:absolute; 
 min-width:100%; min-height:100%; 
 max-width:100%; max-height:100%;`

also you might want to consider renaming the ID :-)

The thing is, when you use an absolute positioned element inside another element (your relative positioned element) - you force the absolute to be exactly the same size. This might not work with an inner relative element.

The unnamed divs you have are `static` as default and behaves more or less like the `relative` positioned elements.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I knew someone would ask. It is auto generated by the CMS.

Comment: Nope. It is still cutting off the image :/

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you have a link for the site? Also, if you use a CMS there might already be a style on your div. Try with !important in your own CSS to see if that is the case. The right approach would then be to eliminate the styling you dont want from the CMS-generated styling afterwards.

Comment: Still being developed. Will post a Fiddle

Comment: is this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/7Lr8nu87/2/

Updated .pageImgHolder with position:absolute; and width:100%;

Comment: Almost! :) How come the background purple isn't resizing? Now to get the background purple resize, this way any content under it just moves up... fluid like. I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lr8nu87/4/
Changed the height of .pageImgHolder to auto.
Also, I see you named the .pageImgHdrSub as a class but marked it with an ID in your HTML.
There is still a little purple space of 4 pixels between the image size and the div it is within. I cannot seem to find where the small space has its origins.

Comment: When you change your . to # on the pageImgHdrSub also set it to position:absolute;
The 4 pixel-problem is the <p> being 4 pixels higher than the <img> inside.

Comment: When I use the absolute position it goes out of the container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63607/discussion-between-searchforknowledge-and-l-h).

Comment: .. This last Fiddle is with the 4 pixels removed. I added an inline style in your HTML code on the <p> saying margin:0 0 -4px 0; 
I would suggest you found the core of the 4 pixel-troll tho.
http://jsfiddle.net/7Lr8nu87/6/

Comment: I will post here should I need any help... and you are NOT inclined to respond, but I would request you do :)

Comment: Okay buddy. You are always welcome to send a link to me with the new questions you could have, and I will try to assist you accordingly. Take care!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following lines

```
min-width = '1000px'; // or any size you desire. It will set the minimum width
max-width = '1250px'; // or any size you desire. It will set the maximum width
min-height = '100%'; // or any size you desire
```

To the class "`pageImgHolder div div p img`"

```
.pageImgHolder div div p img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        min-width = '1000px'; // or any size you desire
        max-width = '1250px'; // or any size you desire
        min-height = '500px'; // or any size you desire
    }
```

Also add min and max properties in

```
<img src="theImages/dummyBanner.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```

like

```
<img src="theImages/dummyBanner.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto; min-width:900px; max-width:1000px;" />
```

Comment: the main DIV always max-width is 1100 and max height is 337

Comment: You can set according to your need i just tried to give a reference.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lr8nu87/ (The image isn't resizing for some reason)

Comment: if there is a problem with the code you can use !important keyword in css to force that property to it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and used first a table with width 100% and the div inside the table with the same, also without borders or paddings all set to 0 try it and tell me how it works. Tablets are old stuff but if you make them work together with divs then you will never more have troubles with divs